# How we can Export a php page in PDF while using Localhost?

Tags: php, pdf, export

I'm trying to export my php page into PDF. i have searched and found 'pdf2html' but i think it's only support for HTTP link, but i want to work at localhost. is there any other tool for this?

Thanks in advance for your help..

Answer (score 0):

I've used **Yii** Framework some time ago with **MPDF** for some reports.

You could check the website: [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)